# Question regarding polygons

Tags: geometry, integer-lattices, polygons

Can you prove, that if a equilateral lattice n-gon is constructible, then there will be such a polygon for which the sides have minimal length?

Comment: This is trivial because the set of lengths in a lattice is well-ordered.

Comment: I was writing an answer to that effect, and then I wondered if perhaps the question isn't exactly "how do I prove that this set is well-ordered?"  It clearly is, but I don't offhand know how to show this, other than by explicitly constructing an order isomorphism with $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Lengths in a lattice are square roots of positive integers, so clearly they're well-ordered: $1 < \sqrt{2} < \sqrt{3} < ...$.

Comment: $\sqrt3$ is not in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of possible side lengths is exactly the set $S$ of all positive numbers of the form $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for integers $a$ and $b$.  In increasing order, its elements are $$\{1, \sqrt2, 2, \sqrt 5, \sqrt8, 3, \sqrt{10}, \ldots\}.$$
This set $S$ is well-ordered, which means that every nonempty subset of $S$ contains a minimal element. (It is well-ordered because it is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb N$, the positive integers, which is also well-ordered.)

Since any constructible lattice $n$-gon must have a side length from $S$, the set of constructible side lengths $C$ is a subset of $S$.  Since $S$ is well-ordered, $C$ is either empty or has a minimum element, say $m$.  So either there is no constructible lattice $n$-gon at all, or else there is at least one with the minimum side length $m$.

I hope this is something like what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, thank you! My first idea was also to say that it is well ordered because it is order-isomorphic to N, but  I didn't want to complicate. This is nice:)

Comment: But, why a and b non negative integers?

Comment: You're right, it's more properly all nonzero integers.

Comment: The set S is finite?

Comment: Of course it isn't finite.  It's the set of all possible side lengths.